# Creating element using JQuery that takes CSS property in .css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have code that looks like this :

---

style.css

```
#div1{
 height: 1280;
 width: 800;
 top: -5000px;
 position: absolute;

}
#div2{
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;

}
#div3{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
#ball,
#ball1,
#ball2,
#ball3,
#ball4,
#ball5,
#ball6,
#ball7,
#ball8
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

---

game.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); 
function onDeviceReady(){
    //jQuery.fx.interval = 120;
    $("#div1").animate({top:'0px'});
    $("#div2").delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
    $("#div2").animate({height:'75%',width:'75%',top:'12.5%',left:'12.5%'});
    $("#div2").delay(1000).animate({left:'20%'},50).animate({left:'2.5%'},50).animate({left:'12.5%'},50);
    $("#div3").delay(2000).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);


//#ball turn orbit around the fixed pixel
var angle = 0;     // starting position (degrees)
var angle1 = 45;
var angle2 = 90;
var angle3 = 135;
var angle4 = 180;
var angle5 = 225;
var angle6 = 270;
var angle7 = 315;
var angle8 = 0;

var distance = 250; // distance of b from a
var speed = 300;    // revolution speed in degrees per second
var rate  = 10;    // refresh rate in ms

function f() {

    var t = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t1 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle1 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l1 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle1 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t2 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle2 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l2 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle2 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t3 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle3 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l3 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle3 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t4 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle4 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l4 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle4 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t5 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle5 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l5 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle5 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t6 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle6 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l6 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle6 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t7 = 450 + (distance * Math.sin(angle7 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l7 = 350 + (distance * Math.cos(angle7 * Math.PI/180.0));

    var t8 = 450 + (50 * Math.sin(angle8 * Math.PI/180.0));
    var l8 = 350 + (50 * Math.cos(angle8 * Math.PI/180.0));

    $("#ball").css({
        top: t,        
        left: l
    });

    angle += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball1").css({
        top: t1,        
        left: l1
    });

    angle1 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball2").css({
        top: t2,        
        left: l2
    });

    angle2 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball3").css({
        top: t3,        
        left: l3
    });

    angle3 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball4").css({
        top: t4,        
        left: l4
    });

    angle4 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball5").css({
        top: t5,        
        left: l5
    });

    angle5 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball6").css({
        top: t6,        
        left: l6
    });

    angle6 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball7").css({
        top: t7,        
        left: l7
    });

    angle7 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

    $("#ball8").css({
        top: t8,        
        left: l8
    });

    angle8 += (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;

}

setInterval(f, rate);

$("#ball").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball1").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball2").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball3").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball4").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball5").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball6").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball7").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball7").delay(6000).remove();
$("#ball6").delay(6000).remove();
$("#div1").append("<img src='pix/s1.png' id='ball8' />").show(100);

};
```

---

abc.html

```
<html>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/android2_1.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.gamequery-0.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady()">
<div id="div1">
<img src="pix/bg1.jpg" id="bgpic" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
<img src="pix/item1.png" id="div2" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball1" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball2" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball3" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball4" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball5" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball6" />
<img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball7" />
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

but the code doens't seems to work. I did try to google it.
And what i get is .addClass() which is not work too.

Hope you guys can help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

---

Guys, my bad.

i found my problem.

instead of this,

```
$("#div1").append("<img src='pix/s1.png' id='ball8' />").show(100);
```

I should write this

```
$("#div1").append("<img src='pix/s1.png' id='ball8' />");
$("#ball8").show(100);
```

Comment: Have you wrapped your code in a `$.ready()` function?

Comment: yup, i did that.
it work when i put my code like this
$("#div1").append("<img src='pix/s1.png' id='ball8' style='height: 100px; width: 100px;' />");

Comment: what do you mean it's not working, any error message? BTW your image is `display:none;`

Comment: Have you checked for same DOM id for other DOM.

Comment: Jonathan: just ignore that display: none;, and there is no error message.

Dipesh: DOM id ? how to check that? (Sorry I'm newbie)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jXxhx/ here it is working properly

Comment: BTW where have you used `.addClass()` why do you receive this error message. May be this code works fine but the code above it has some fault, so JavaScript stops there and doesn't execute further. Check your codes above this or paste your entire JS

Comment: I did not receive any error message when using .addClass(), but it is not suitable because I use "#ball8" instead of ".ball8". <br>
Jonathan: I see your code there works. But I dunno what happen to my code and it doesn't work at my .js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were including the links in `html` instead of `head` tag.

change your html file as shown below:

```
<html>

<head>
   <!-- All plugin references should be inside head tag -->
   <!-- Added -->
   <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 

   <!-- Your plugins here -->
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/android2_1.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.gamequery-0.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady()">
   <div id="div1">
     <img src="pix/bg1.jpg" id="bgpic" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" />
     <img src="pix/item1.png" id="div2" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball1" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball2" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball3" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball4" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball5" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball6" />
     <img src="pix/s1.png" id="ball7" />
  </div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

```
setInterval(f, rate);
$("#div1").append("<img src='pix/s1.png' id='ball8' />");
$("#ball").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball1").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball2").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball3").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball4").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball5").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball6").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball7").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball8").delay(4000).show(100);
$("#ball7").delay(6000).remove();
$("#ball6").delay(6000).remove();
```

Comment: There is no error show, just that the element i created does not receive the css property.

Comment: @EdsTan Seems to work for me  http://jsbin.com/epejil/1/edit ? If I remove `display:none`

Comment: I found some different.
what is the different between $(function(){}); and document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true); 
function onDeviceReady(){};

Comment: my html body does this,
<body onload='onDeviceReady()'>

Comment: @EdsTan on which device you working on? Is it related to desktop?

Comment: Mac book using chrome browser and eclipse build in browser

Comment: @EdsTan Did you get the solution for your problem? If so what was the error? If you didn't get the solution then please post the js file, and html file (just related code).

Comment: I posted my entire file. Thanks for helping me =)

Comment: @EdsTan You shouldn't mark as an answer if you didn't find the solution yet. If you mark before itself then other users will think that you got the solution and might leave without helping you. Anyway, Iam still trying to understand the bug.

Comment: @EdsTan you forgot to link the jquery mobile plugins..
`<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>` keep this in your head tag.

Comment: But the "#ball8" still does not appear. When i inspect the element on the web browser, the "#ball8" does not receive the css property.

Comment: if you notice, I've set the "#ball8" distance to nearer, so that I can spot it easily. Run it at browser and inspect the element, you cant find "#ball8" exist in the page.

Comment: @EdsTan Its seems to be simple problem of filepath. Try once `$("#div1").append("<img src='../pix/s1.png' id='ball8' />");`

Comment: @EdsTan please check my update. you forgot to keep `show()` for the `#ball8`. when I kept `show()` for `#ball8`, its working. check this fiddle http://jsbin.com/udevic/5/edit

Comment: Thanks Mr.Green for helping me to clear my careless mistake. Great Thanks !

Comment: @EdsTan always pleasure :)

Comment: @EdsTan you are increasing the value which will  become very large if the program runs for a long time... do the following `angle = (angle +(speed * (rate/1000)) % 360) % 360;` instead of `angle += angle +(speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;` in your js file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error just that the new element doesn't have the styles applied to it? The element is being created, it's just not styled properly?

If so, it's probably because you're using an ID rather than a class to assign the styles. The stylesheet is interpreted before the script. The styles which apply to the id are ignored because the element you're targeting doesn't exist at the time the CSS is interpreted. If you changed your CSS selector from `#ball8` to `.ball8` and then changed the image's id to a class, it would probably work. If you really need that image to have the "ball8" id, then just use a different class for the styles.

Answer (score 0):

You used display none for image. you have to show image in jquery.
Try this code:

game.js

```
$('<img />', {
   id:'ball8'
}).appendTo('#div1').attr('src', 'pix/s1.png').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily with addClass, but it does not work because you got an Id instead of  class.

try this

```
.ball8 { height: 100px;width: 100px; position: absolute; display: none; }

game.js

$("#div1").addClass('ball8');
```

And don't forget to make it visible with something like this:

```
$('.ball8').show()
```